# VIM - How can I store vim bookmarks in sessions files?

Tags: session, vim, ide

How can I store the bookmarks belonging to a session not belonging to a file ? I want to have multiple sessions and each one have different bookmarks for the same files. I want to mimic an IDE behavior.

BR

Comment: Are you using bookmark to mean marks? uppercase? or lowercase? I am not for sure but I can not find any documentation that lowercase marks are stored in sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File marks are stored in the *viminfo* file, not in sessions, and there's unfortunately no value in `'sessionoptions'` that would enable that.

So, there's no easy solution, just workarounds that are more involved. Some ideas:

- You can write separate viminfo files via `:wviminfo [file]`, and then read them via `:rviminfo`. You could use that (maybe with a tweak to the `'viminfo'` option to reduce what gets written) in addition to session files.
- Write / find a bookmark plugin that persists in an uppercased global variable, which is captured in a session via the `globals` value.
- Extend a plugin like [session.vim - Extended session management for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150) that does post-processing of the written session, anyway, and add the marks info (via `:call setpos("'[mark]", ...)` in there.